# ggplotly does not display within an html document

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, ggplotly

I want to write an html_document where the reader can select different versions of a graph.  I want to use ggplotly so the reader can hover over points and see their labels and so forth.  The ggplotly works when run outside of the html_document but does nothing when run from within the document.

Here is the code (I added a # in front of  ``` that are part of the RMD file, so it will look like one set of code, to run please remove.)  The second option works but the first does not.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "DWD"
date: "2023-05-18"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

#```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
#```

This R Markdown document is made interactive using Shiny. Unlike the more traditional workflow of creating static reports, you can now create documents that allow your readers to change the assumptions underlying your analysis and see the results immediately. 

To learn more, see [Interactive Documents](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

#```{r eruptions1, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
inputPanel(
  selectInput("option2",
    label = "Which Option?",
    choices = c(1, 2), selected = 1
  ),
)

renderPlot({
  thetas <- seq(0, 1, length = 150) * 2 * pi
  decay <- 1:150
  if (input$option2 == 1) {
    dsn <- data.frame(xx = exp(-decay * .01) * sin(thetas), yy = exp(-decay * .01) * cos(thetas))
    plot0 <- ggplot(dsn, aes(x = xx, y = yy)) +
      suppressWarnings(geom_point(size = 1, aes(col = decay, text = decay)))
    g <- ggplotly(plot0)
    g
  } else {
    dsn <- data.frame(xx = exp(-decay * 0) * sin(thetas), yy = exp(-decay * 0) * cos(thetas))
    g <- ggplot(dsn, aes(x = xx, y = yy)) +
      suppressWarnings(geom_point(size = 1, aes(col = decay, text = decay)))
    g
  }
})
#```
````

Answer (score 2):

That's because rendering a (gg)plotly graphic requires `renderPlotly`, not `renderPlot`. You can do as follows :

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "DWD"
date: "2023-05-18"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

This R Markdown document is made interactive using Shiny. Unlike the more traditional workflow of creating static reports, you can now create documents that allow your readers to change the assumptions underlying your analysis and see the results immediately. 

To learn more, see [Interactive Documents](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

```{r eruptions1, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
inputPanel(
  selectInput("option2",
    label = "Which Option?",
    choices = c(1, 2), selected = 1
  ),
)

renderUI({
  thetas <- seq(0, 1, length = 150) * 2 * pi
  decay <- 1:150
  dsn <- data.frame(xx = exp(-decay * .01) * sin(thetas), yy = exp(-decay * .01) * cos(thetas))
  plot0 <- ggplot(dsn, aes(x = xx, y = yy)) +
      suppressWarnings(geom_point(size = 1, aes(col = decay, text = decay)))
  if(input$option2 == 1) {
    renderPlotly({ggplotly(plot0)})
  } else {
    renderPlot({plot0})
  }
})
```
````

Comment: the above works, but if instead of using if (input$option1 ==1) {} else {} I do if(input$option2==1){} ; if(input$option2==2){} it doesn't work.  Any idea why I would get this?